# Writing multi-page Big Tiff saving in C++

Tags: image, save, tiff, geotiff, libtiff.net

I am writing an application to save multi-page tiff saving with [big tiff library](http://bigtiff.org/) and I have two problems with the big tiff library:

1. So far I am able to save some images in a stack, but with [the image viewer](https://www.irfanview.com/) I can only see 3 or 4 pages even though the file size for the image stack is much larger than 4 images; I expect to see more images. I followed the example [here](https://gist.github.com/jcupitt/ba60e4e1100607d7a5cc9c19e2ec11e8).

   ```
   //open
   TIFFOpen(destPtr, "w8");
   //set
   TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, width);
   TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, height);
   TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE, bitsPerSample);
   TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATION_TOPLEFT);
   TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_PLANARCONFIG, PLANARCONFIG_CONTIG);
   TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_COMPRESSION, COMPRESSION_NONE); //either one works
   TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_FILLORDER, FILLORDER_MSB2LSB);
   TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_ROWSPERSTRIP, 8);
   TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_PHOTOMETRIC, PHOTOMETRIC_MINISBLACK);
   TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_SAMPLESPERPIXEL, 1);
   TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_MAXSAMPLEVALUE, maxSampleValue);

   //loop
   for (int i =0; i<=10; i++)
   {
       // stack
       TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_SUBFILETYPE, FILETYPE_PAGE);
       // set the page number
       TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_PAGENUMBER, i, 10);

       int width = 5056;
       int height = 2960;

       tdata_t l_buffer;
       unsigned long l_buffer_size = width * 2;
       l_buffer = _TIFFmalloc(l_buffer_size);
       unsigned short *da = (unsigned short*)data;

       for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
       {
           memcpy(l_buffer, &da[row*width], l_buffer_size);


           int ret = TIFFWriteScanline(out, l_buffer, row, 0);
           if (ret == -1)
           {
               TIFFClose(out);
           }
       }
       _TIFFfree(l_buffer);
   }

   //close
   (void)TIFFClose(out);
   ```
2. If I use TIFFWriteRawStrip() then there is offset in the image and I can't view all the images even though the stack seems to contain all the images. With the regular tiff library this code worked just fine.

   ```
   //open
   TIFFOpen(destPtr, "w8");
   //set
   TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, width);
   TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, height);
   TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE, bitsPerSample);
   TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATION_TOPLEFT);
   TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_PLANARCONFIG, PLANARCONFIG_CONTIG);
   TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_COMPRESSION, COMPRESSION_NONE); //either one works
   TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_FILLORDER, FILLORDER_MSB2LSB);

   TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_PHOTOMETRIC, PHOTOMETRIC_MINISBLACK);
   TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_SAMPLESPERPIXEL, 1);
   TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_MAXSAMPLEVALUE, maxSampleValue);

   //loop
   for (int i =0; i<=10; i++)
   {
       // stack
       TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_SUBFILETYPE, FILETYPE_PAGE);
       // set the page number
       TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_PAGENUMBER, i, 10);

       TIFFWriteRawStrip((TIFF*)out, (tstrip_t)0, (tdata_t)data, (tsize_t)length);
   }

   //close
   (void)TIFFClose(out);
   ```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0goNF.jpg)

I figured out. The following code will do the job.

```
tif = TIFFOpen(destPtr, "w");

int npages = 10;


for (int i = 0; i < npages; i++)
{
    TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, height);
    TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, width);
    TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_PLANARCONFIG, PLANARCONFIG_CONTIG);
    TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_SAMPLESPERPIXEL, 1);
    TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_COMPRESSION, COMPRESSION_NONE);
    TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE, 16);
    TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_ROWSPERSTRIP, 8);

    TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_SUBFILETYPE, FILETYPE_PAGE);
    TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_PAGENUMBER, i, npages);

    // not sure if this is needed...
    TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_PHOTOMETRIC, PHOTOMETRIC_MINISBLACK);
    TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_FILLORDER, FILLORDER_MSB2LSB);
    TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATION_TOPLEFT);


    //TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT, RESUNIT_CENTIMETER);
    //TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION, pixels_per_cm);
    //TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION, pixels_per_cm);


    //tdata_t       l_buffer;
    //unsigned long l_buffer_size = width * 2; // LINE buffer for 16bit
    //l_buffer = _TIFFmalloc(l_buffer_size);

    char*dat = (char*)data;

    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
        //memcpy(l_buffer, &data[row*width], l_buffer_size);

        int ret = TIFFWriteScanline(tif, dat + row * width * 2, row, 0);
        if (ret == -1) {
            TIFFClose(tif);
            return -1;
        }
    }
    TIFFWriteDirectory(tif);
}
//_TIFFfree(l_buffer);
TIFFClose(tif);
```

---